# Removing digits from a column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column in Excel with names followed by numbers. I need to remove the numbers from all the names, how do I do that?

My column and rows B2:B6718 follow this pattern: Name (6digit_number)

I need to remove the (number) and the brackets surrounding the number.

```
Administration af fast ejendom på kontraktbasis (683210)
Administration af og bidrag til erhvervsfremme (841300)
Administration af sundhedsvæsen, undervisning, kultur og soc (841200)
Agenturhandel med blandet sortiment (461900)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Replace tool (ctrl+H), just replace `(*)` by nothing !

Answer (score 0):

how about

=MID( RIGHT(B3,8) ,2,6)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
=MID(B3,1,LEN(B3)-9)
```